# CFLDAP No Results Returned

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap

I'm an LDAP noob and am trying to query an LDAP server to get a list of users who have 'smith' in their username.  I'm getting an empty result set from the code below.  Any help is as always appreciated.

(note: I've verified the connection info by connecting via Softerra LDAP Browser)

```
<cfldap 
    server = "#variables.server#"
    port = "#variables.port#"
    username="#variables.username#"
    password="#variables.password#"
    action="query" 
    name="results" 
    start="DC=hsd1"
    filter="((&(objectClass=user))(samaccountname=*smith*))"
    attributes = "cn,o,l,st,sn,c,mail,telephonenumber, givenname,homephone, streetaddress, postalcode, SamAccountname, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, department">
```

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess (which I do) I would say the problem is probably with your "start" attribute.  In my experience, the start usually contains a more well-defined DN.  Something like:

```
start="dc=dirDomain,dc=domain,dc=topLevelDomain"
```

So if for example if the domain you log into is hsd1.mydomain.com then it would be

```
start="dc=hsd1,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
```

The problem could also be with your filter. I think you may have too many parans.

Maybe try something like this:

```
filter="(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*smith*))"
```